# File permission issue with apache+mod_wsgi with pyramid&pyramid_beaker

Tags: amazon-ec2, mod-wsgi, file-permissions, pyramid, beaker

I am trying to set up a pyramid app. I am using wsgi and apache2.

I keep getting Internal server error and the contents of the apache log is

```
 mod_wsgi (pid=11200): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/ubuntu/modwsgi/env/pyramid.wsgi'.
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/ubuntu/modwsgi/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyramid-1.3-py2.6.egg/pyramid/router.py", line 191, in __call__
     request._process_response_callbacks(response)
   File "/home/ubuntu/modwsgi/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyramid-1.3-py2.6.egg/pyramid/request.py", line 243, in _process_response_callbacks
     callback(self, response)
   File "/home/ubuntu/modwsgi/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyramid_beaker-0.6.1-py2.6.egg/pyramid_beaker/__init__.py", line 26, in session_callback
     self.persist()
   File "/home/ubuntu/modwsgi/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Beaker-1.6.3-py2.6.egg/beaker/session.py", line 706, in persist
     self._session().save()
   File "/home/ubuntu/modwsgi/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Beaker-1.6.3-py2.6.egg/beaker/session.py", line 400, in save
     **self.namespace_args)
   File "/home/ubuntu/modwsgi/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Beaker-1.6.3-py2.6.egg/beaker/container.py", line 622, in __init__
     util.verify_directory(self.file_dir)
   File "/home/ubuntu/modwsgi/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Beaker-1.6.3-py2.6.egg/beaker/util.py", line 85, in verify_directory
     os.makedirs(dir)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/os.py", line 150, in makedirs
     makedirs(head, mode)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
     mkdir(name, mode)
 OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'beaker_dir'
```

I can use simple pserve to serve the page and run `wget http://localhost:6543/user/form` on the terminal. It works well with form getting downloaded. But over the browser I get the 500 error.

I am using EC2 to host the app.

In the app:main stanza I am using the following code:

```
session.type = file
session.data_dir = beaker_dir
session.key = mvc
session.encrypt_key = mysecretencryptionkey
session.validate_key = mysecretvalidationkey
session.cookie_on_exception = true
```

Thanks a lot for reading

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supply an absolute path for:

```
session.data_dir = beaker_dir
```

The current working directory could be anything, usually '/', and so path will be wrong.